# Fluid doesn't fall

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm quite new in blender but this is really strange, please help!
I want to simulate water flowing between letters and I have two issues:

- the water doesn't fall down but stays at distance from the obstacle
- some water goes below a fluid-obstacle

I already made a simple fluid simulation of water into a container and worked fine. 
The image below is a side-view.
[image]